# soap with windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap

how can i access a soap server (with php) from wp7 and send requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the "Add Service Reference" option when you right click on your project in Visual Studio to create a proxy class using the WSDL for your Web Service. For more details check this blog post about adding [Windows Phone Web Service Reference](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2010/12/30/windows-phone-7-building-a-simple-dictionary-web-client.aspx) or watch the [Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse_wp7silverlight_unit) video series on Channel 9.

Comment: Hi... Greg Bray, I am trying to use PHP soap server in my windows phone 8 project.
The second Link you suggested is not working any more. Can you please update the link if you have. Thanks